# PhotoShop CC 2014 uses too much disk space

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have the following problem with Photoshop: When I open up a document (approx. 15MB), PhotoShop uses 5 to 7GB disk storage immediately.

When working with smaller documents it just takes more time but in every case my disk runs out of space in several hours.

Why does the application put SO MUCH stuff onto the hard drive?! Especially regarding the fact that I gave PhotoShop about 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should be written as comment. But my reputation is quite low to add a comment.

Anyway, I didn't use CC version yet. I've used Photoshop CS6 so far. Photoshop has a performance settings option that lets you choose the amount of RAM, Scratch Disk and Cache size for images.

You can go to the Edit > Preferences > Performance.
Now set your delegated RAM for Photoshop, History and Cache Size. 
Also choose your scratch disk.

And you should also check the amount of virtual RAM available. You can increase your virtual RAM as -

Right Click on My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Performance > Settings > Advanced > Virtual Memory > Change > Uncheck Automatic Option > Custom > Choose a Volume for Virtual RAM > Set Custom Virtual RAM.

Note: If your RAM is 8 GB, you can set another 8 GB as virtual RAM. Or more if you want.

Waiting for your response. Inform us whether this system works or not. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using Max OS! In the performance settings I don't see any Scratch Disk options... I'm using the german version, but maybe you can check if I just don't see them... http://imgur.com/cwdqb4v

Comment: Everything I mentioned is there! You can't see because your version is German. Increase RAM 55% to 80%. Arbeitsvolume is your scratch disk.

Comment: I see. But I can just select the disk, I don't see where I change its size...

Comment: Maybe you've just one disk. Anyway, you can try reinstalling. :)

Comment: Yes, I just have one. But I'd like to know how to reduce the disk usage. I know how to change the disk. I don't think it's okay that PS takes that much space... Reinstalling doesn't help

Comment: I think you should uninstall Photoshop and then install it again. You can also check whether older version of Photoshop (if u have one) does the same thing or not. You have a Mac PC. But I'm a Windows lover. So can't share any tips regarding OS :(